# What are the basic differences differences between the browsers powered by Gecko and by those powered by Webkit?

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome, webkit, gecko

I wanted to know about the basic differences between the browsers powered by Gecko and Webkit?
- Are there any differences in the way they render?
- Any difference in the mechanism they use to render?

Any other differences?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Gecko and Webkit are different rendering engines.
- Yes, they use somewhat different rendering mechanisms.
- Yes, the results sometimes look different, though that usually indicates a bug in either WebKit or Gecko or both.
- Gecko-based browsers use SpiderMonkey as their JavaScript engine, while WebKit-based ones use either JavaScriptCore or V8.
- Different browsers use different networking libraries (Gecko-based ones use necko, while WebKit-based ones use a variety of different libraries).

Comment: thanks for pointing out all those diferences, I've found this link useful too : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines

Answer (score 2):

There is a Wikipedia page listing the differences of layout engines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5). One main difference between these mainstream layout engines seems to be that the set of tags they support can be quite different. Though those tags might be seldom used/can be emulated by CSS or JS anyways.